# OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) Macport issues

Tags: clang, macports, osx-elcapitan, gcc4

I tried to run $ sudo port upgrade outdated on my Mac and had build issues
with: 
gcc48, 
texlive-bin
clang-3.5
clang-3.7, 
etc.

Macports has some of the issues I've encountered:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48471

I tried applying the patch (define_non_standard_clang_macros.patch ) from the Macport incident above and I also manually updating: /usr/include/Availability.h

```
$ sudo patch /usr/include/Availability.h define_non_standard_clang_macros.patch 
Password:
patching file /usr/include/Availability.h
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1141.
patch: **** Can't rename file /usr/include/Availability.h to /usr/include/Availability.h.orig : Operation not permitted

$ sudo cp Availability.h /usr/include/Availability.h
cp: /usr/include/Availability.h: Operation not permitted
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On El Capitan, you can no longer modify any files in /usr. The feature is called System Integrity Protection and is also known under it's development name "rootless".

It is also a bad idea to start patching a system header. If the header needs fixing, that's a problem that should be reported to Apple via a rdar for them to correct.

Comment: Reported to Apple 'rdar' as issue 23061144.